# Asking for advice in choosing a package to do a particular task

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is it good practice to ask something like 'what are the best packages to add a nomeclature? How do they compare?'

It sounds useful to me but I have read some have prejudices (that I somehow share) against 'best pratices question' (see for example [this question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1246/dont-ask-us-about-best-practices-glom-of-nit-or-mrs-cake)).

Where to draw the line ?

Comment: Could you point to the statements concerning 'best practice' questions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have a number of great questions that don't directly ask for the "best" package, but for advantages and disadvantages of different solutions/packages, one of which I asked myself: [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib). There's usually two ways these questions turn out to be answered: Either with one consolidated answer, which usually is (mainly) by one author; or one answer per package/solution/approach. The latter tend to be Community Wiki (CW) questions, tagged with [big-list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list).

But in general, these questions are great questions! They tend to require a bit more thought on the side of the asker in order to turn out great, i.e. you should really go away from your specific situation, and try to come up with and ask about general criteria that might play a role in the choice of such a tool. My bottom line is probably that such questions shouldn't lead to "one single best package" being picked out -- because that's often simply not possible in the objective manner that's required here -- but they should display and compare features of different packages, so that the reader of the question can make an informed decision on which package to choose.

More such questions:

- [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation)
- [List of Indexing Packages - Pros and Cons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51603/list-of-indexing-packages-pros-and-cons)
- [Best way to generate a nice function plots in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/best-way-to-generate-a-nice-function-graph-in-latex)